# how can i apply css border along with css padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a requirement to conditional highlight a menu item for an existing application. To highlight the item i am using a bottom border for that particular item. But there is a already a padding that is being applied and the highlighted line need to be at the bottom(attached images for reference)

```css
.menulist {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  transition: height .3s;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

.menulist .menulist-menu-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: inherit;
}

.menulist .menulist_nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.71;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

.menulist_bottom_border {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: gray;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="menulist">
  <div class="menulist-menu-bar">
    <div>
      <ul class="menulist_nav">
        <div class="menulist_bottom_border">nav1</div>
        <div>nav2</div>
        <div>nav3</div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, it is working. See this:-

```css
.menulist {
      background: white;
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      transition: height .3s;
      z-index: 9;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .menulist .menulist-menu-bar {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 8px;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      position: relative;
    }

    .menulist .menulist_nav {
      padding-left: 0;
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.71;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: stretch;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .menulist_bottom_border {
      border-bottom: 2px solid;
      border-color: gray;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<header class="menulist">
  <div class="menulist-menu-bar">
    <div>
      <ul class="menulist_nav">
        <div class="menulist_bottom_border">nav1</div>
        <div class="menulist_bottom_border">nav2</div>
        <div class="menulist_bottom_border">nav3</div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

You were seeing unexpected things because only one of the div had the class menulist bottom border. Since most elems have the flex display property, so it looked like that.

Comment: My question is not about having bottom border for all items, if you run the code snippet you will observe the highlight line for item is coming above the padding and I want it something like shown in image along with padding.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question explaining my thoughts that may help you.

> 1. The padding between text and border-bottom is because of `line-hight: 1.71;`
> 2. The yellow padding shown in image is because of the padding applied on class `menulist-menu-bar`.

If you want to remove any of these then you can play on these value to get desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I can’t remove the padding as it is existing application and that is required to be there.